# Mixing of @SessionScoped and @Model in CDI documentation

Tags: java, annotations, java-ee-6, cdi

Java EE 6 newcomer question ahead, so beware...

I keep reading introductory CDI material like

http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#d0e268

I'm wondering throughout that document why they are mixing `@SessionScoped` with [@Model](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Model.html), which is defined as being `@RequestScoped` plus `@Named` and a few other things I don't understand.

Why aren't the beans, e.g. the Login bean, simply annotated with `@Named` + `@SessionScoped`? What's the gain here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right using `@Named`@SessionScoped`would achieve the same and would be clearer. In fact I wonder if some CDI impl couldn't throw an exception with this double scope (Weld doesn't).

BTW I encourage you to read Weld documentation which is a more concrete approach to CDI IMHO.